# Laravel get multiple objects in the same panel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to get a list of the staffs on my application.

So now I got this view:

```
@foreach($getteam as $team)

 <!-- Begin row -->
  <div class="panel-group col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ $team->role->name }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <img src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/public/img/avatar.jpg" style="float:left;margin-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;" class="img-circle" alt="{{ $team->username }}" width="75" height="75">
            <h4 style="color:{{ $team->role->colour }};">{{ $team->username }}</h4>
            <p>Een klein beetje info over wie ik ben enzo... :p</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <!-- End row -->
@endforeach
```

With this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `role` ON `user`.`role_id` = `role`.`id`
WHERE `role_id` >= '4'
ORDER BY `role`.`id` DESC
```

or

```
User::with('Role')
    ->join('role', 'user.role_id', '=', 'role.id')
    ->where('role_id', '>=', '4')
    ->orderBy('role.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Now, so for so good,

This works to get the users exept this is the result:
http://prntscr.com/8a6v60

That is **not** what I want.

This is what I want: http://prntscr.com/8a6vgo

So when the groups are the same, they need to be in the same `UL`.

**Edit**
This is my view now:

```
<!-- Begin row -->
<div class="panel-group col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
  @foreach($roles as $role)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ $role->name }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">

          @foreach($role->user() as $user)
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <img src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/public/img/avatar.jpg" style="float:left;margin-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;" class="img-circle" alt="{{ $user->username }}" width="75" height="75">
              <h4 style="color:{{ $role->colour }};">{{ $user->username }}</h4>
              <p>Een klein beetje info over wie ik ben enzo... :p</p>
            </li>
          @endforeach

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
<!-- End row -->
```

This is the controller:

```
public function ForumTeam()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        $getTeam = User::with('Role')->join('role', 'user.role_id', '=', 'role.id')->where('role_id', '>=', '4')->orderBy('role.id', 'DESC')->get();
        return View::make('team')->with('getteam', $getTeam)->with('roles', $roles);
    }
```

And this one is the model.

```
<?php
class Role extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'role';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

Now I only get all the role names, not the correct stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the reverse of the relationship between users and roles. Instead of fetching the users, get the roles and for each role you can get the corresponding users (this of course requires the `Role` model to have a `users()` method with a relation defined:

```
// You can of course use conditions here to filter out what roles you want loaded
$roles = Role::all();
```

Then iterate through the roles, and for each role iterate through its users:

```
<div class="panel-group col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
  @foreach($roles as $role)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ $role->name }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">

          @foreach($role->users as $user)
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <img src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/public/img/avatar.jpg" style="float:left;margin-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;" class="img-circle" alt="{{ $user->username }}" width="75" height="75">
              <h4 style="color:{{ $role->colour }};">{{ $user->username }}</h4>
              <p>Een klein beetje info over wie ik ben enzo... :p</p>
            </li>
          @endforeach

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: That is possible, but I have more then 1'role'. So right now, when I try to show another role, he displays everything in the same panel... This is what I want at the end: http://prntscr.com/8a7re7 and not this: http://prntscr.com/8a7rhn since test-user is another role.

Comment: Ive updated your answer to what I have now. Now I get just ALL the roles (titles) [http://prntscr.com/8a81ag] but with nothing in it...

Comment: Please update your original question with the relevant code, not the answer.

Comment: If a user can have only one role, then you have a **one-to-many** relation and the `Role` model should have this relation defined like this `$this->hasMany('App\User);`, not `$this->belongsTo('App\User);`.

Comment: Also the second `@foreach` in your view should iterate `$role->user` (access it as a property), not `$role->user()`, because accesing the relation as a method will return the relation object, not the collection of users.